# Java Factory Pattern with Enum

Tags: java, design-patterns

i have to use the factory pattern with singleton.
My Factory Class creates two different objects depending on an enum type.

what is the best way to return the right object.

solution 1: by an if-else decision in the factory:

```
if(enumType == "objectA") return new objectA()
```

solution 2: the enum class has a return function:

```
enum ObjectType{ ObjectA{ .. return new ObjectA()..}}
```

thx, mike

Comment: sorry, i've troubles to edit this post. i've forgotten: Hi there :)

Comment: I prefer solution 2, but if you insist on solution 1, I think using a `switch` statement would be slightly better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write a function on the enum. That way you're not going to forget to add a clause to your factory method when you add a new enum.

As a rule, I'd favour polymorphism and method implementation over sequences of `if`/`else if` etc. for virtually any solution. It's much less error prone, and issues will be caught at compile time, not run time.

Comment: The only reason I could think of for not doing it this way would if the `enum` were not under your control which is presumably not the case here.

Comment: If there are a lot of different ways to dispatch on enum member, and each way is used only once in code, `switch` is better than method dispatch. This is quite rare in practice, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you can only have two instances of a class, I would use an Enum unless it need to have another class as a super-class.